# Apache - redirecting to same URL but with query string appended

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a rewrite rule on Apache where it rewrites the url to append a query string to the end:

```
http://example.org/page1.aspx
```

goes to

```
http://example.org/page1.aspx?query=12345
```

Problem is when I apply this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^\/page1.aspx$ http://example.org.aspx?query12345 [NC,L,R=301]
```

I end up getting a redirect loop.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a condition to check if query string is empty first:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?page1\.aspx$ %{REQUEST_URI}?query=12345 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Superb! Thanks a lot for the speedy reply, it works. :)